# Class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I am having issues with the commented segment it is giving off this error:

> E:\School stuff\Java\Assign7_Polk.java:60: error: method FindMax in class ScanArray cannot be applied to given types;
>   int highest = findarray.FindMax();
>   required: int[]
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I Don't know what else to do should it be given a different Name?

```
class ScanArray {

    int Max = 0;

    {
    }

    int FindMax(int[] grades) {
        int Max = grades[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] > Max) {
                Max = grades[i];
            }
        }
        return Max;
    }

    int FindMin(int[] grades) {
        int Min = grades[0];
        for (int i = 1; i > grades.length; i++) {
            if (grades[i] < Min) {
                Min = grades[i];
            }
        }
        return Min;

        ScanArray findarray = new ScanArray();

        //Here is the issue!
        int highest = findarray.FindMax();
        int lowest = findarray.FindMin();

        System.out.println("The highest grade is " + highest);
        System.out.println("The lowest grade is " + lowest);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `findarray.FindMax()`. What does your `FindMax` method expect? Basically, where should it look to find the max?

Comment: How is the array that you're trying to find the minimum & maximum values of getting into your code?  Is this part of a program that interrogates the user for values?  And more importantly, is that array actually a member of the `ScanArray` class?  Whether it is or not will affect what the best way to fix this error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing an array to either of your functions (which should be `findMax` and `findMin` with Java naming conventions) -

```
int [] grades = new int[] {1,2,3};
//Here is the issue!
int highest = findarray.FindMax(grades); // <-- pass in some grades.
int lowest = findarray.FindMin(grades);
```